# How to resolve high CPU + excessive stat("/etc/localtime") and clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME) calls

Tags: debian, ruby-on-rails, cpu-usage, ruby-on-rails-3, strace

I've been experiencing really high CPU on a ruby on rails app (see stack below) and have been trying to diagnose the possible causes to no avail.

### **Stack:**

- ruby 1.9.3
- rails 3.2.6
- Apache/2.2.21 (Debian)
- Phusion Passenger 3.0.11

Whenever I run `strace` against the spiking  Rack process PID (*see Top excerpt below*), I am seeing a tonne of `stat("/etc/localtime")` and `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME)` calls and have no idea how to stop these.

## **Excerpt from Top showin running PID:**

> ```
>   PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
> 11674 www-user  20   0  313m 182m 5076 R   99  2.3  63:04.60 Rack: /var/www/my_rails_app/current
> 11634 www-user  20   0  411m 216m 5144 S   10  2.7 197:55.63 Rack: /var/www/my_rails_app/current
> ```

## **Strace snippet below:**

> ```
> [pid 11674] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
> [pid 11674] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
> [pid 11674] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
> [pid 11674] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
> [pid 11674] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354058955, 141474018}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354058955, 141577456}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354058955, 143073982}) = 0
> [pid 11674] poll([{fd=15, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
> [pid 11674] write(15, "b\0\0\0\3SELECT `images`.* FROM `ima"..., 102) = 102
> [pid 11674] read(15, "\1\0\0\1\0229\0\0\2\3def\23myappy_productio"..., 16384) = 2063
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354058955, 144138035}) = 0
> [pid 11674] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
> [pid 11674] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
> [pid 11674] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
> [pid 11674] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
> ...
> [pid 11674] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
> [pid 11674] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
> [pid 11674] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
> [pid 11674] stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=118, ...}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354058955, 154076443}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354058955, 154189429}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354058955, 157185700}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354058955, 157298770}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354058955, 165076003}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354058955, 165212572}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354058955, 167542679}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354058955, 167683436}) = 0
> ....
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354060036, 62052248}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354060036, 62182486}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354060036, 62919948}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354060036, 63057266}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354060036, 63751707}) = 0
>  [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354060036, 73730686}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354060036, 75874687}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354060036, 76077133}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354060036, 78205019}) = 0
> ...
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354060036, 89370879}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354060036, 89583247}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354060036, 91637614}) = 0
> [pid 11674] clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1354060036, 91782149}) = 0
> ```

Have Google'd around and came across a number of suggestions which I've tried with no success.

## **Things tried so far:**

1. Have tried setting time zone as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554271/how-to-avoid-excessive-stat-etc-localtime-calls-in-strftime-on-linux) 

   Made no difference and issue still persists.

   *Content of my /etc/localtime:*

   > TZif2UTCTZif2UTC 
   >   UTC0
2. Have tried the recommended fix for the leapsecond bug:

   > date -s 'date'

No joy so far.

I'm fresh out of ideas so any help/advice on how to diagnose or resolve would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What application is that PID?

Comment: Hi Shane, I've updated the post to include the details of the PID. PLease let me know what you think.

Comment: Looks like it's something running within ruby that's initiating the calls - are you able to do some digging in the code to see if there's anything that could potentially be looping on something that checks the time?

Comment: I have seen the same problem in a wordpress site running on CentOS+cPanel+Apache server. I want to know how to fix it too.

Comment: Can you run the strace like this strace -ffttTo /tmp/strace.out -p <pid>. and then pastebin the strace.out file somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

**export TZ=:/etc/localtime** also works - it will read the file on start-up and never again - this means daemon processes would need to be re-started, if you ever change the contents of this file.

However, like you, we also run UTC on all our servers, so it never changes.

Can't help you on the "clock_gettime" - however, I would say on VMs we found **time()** to be quite expensive, so we have a daemon process that allocates some shared memory and puts the time in there, then all processes that want to know the time attach to & read the shared memory instead of using the **time()** fn.

Comment: Here is a good explanation about `export TZ=:/etc/localtime`: https://packagecloud.io/blog/set-environment-variable-save-thousands-of-system-calls/

Comment: As this is a `glibc` issue, it's possible you won't see it on Alpine, which uses `musl-libc`

Answer (score 1):

I've found that excessive stats to /etc/localtime are due to missing environment variables.

Try this:

```
echo $TZ
```

If it's blank, then set the variable in the correct location (i.e. /home/apache/.bash_profile). You'll need to set it for the user responsible for running your webserver, then reload the daemon (apachectl graceful etc).

```
TZ='Europe/London'; export TZ
```

Or whatever the correct timezone is for your region (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).